# displaying root folders instead of the public folder

Tags: php

I would like that each time I launch my project that I am redirected on the public folder which contains a file index.php which has routes.

but the behavior I receive is different, I am displayed all the folders in the root.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! don't be too discouraged about close votes, but here are some tips for asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add an apache configuration file (.htaccess or otherwise) to your www root directory and add a `DirectoryIndex index.php` line to that file.

Considering you mention it has routes, you may also want to just rewrite everything to that index file, something like this might work for you:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    # when url does not point to a file and ...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # when url does not point to a directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # redirect everything to index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

This does make the assumption you are using apache, which you didn't actually mention.

Comment: I use apache, I added the .htaccess file to my project but the result is that every time I run my project I always get all my root folders which I don't want.

Comment: @Alain_Kayumba You haven't told us what kind of project it is nor shown any source, there's not that much more I can help with without having a lot more information.

Comment: this is a website that I develop. Is there any way to send a screenshot?

Comment: @Alain_Kayumba: While a picture says more than a thousand words, a github repository may say more than a thousand pictures…  but yes, you can add pictures to your question.

Comment: this a github repository : https://github.com/Alain-Kay/cite.git